# Getting incorrect pixels data from canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, webview, react-native, pixel

1) I have base64 image data, this image was used to draw as an image inside canvas. Later on i retrieved it back as base64, sending it to another service and created an image *(store as image file inside storage)*.

2) In another page, i load back this image as base64, draw back inside canvas. All the rendering part looks good and working perfectly.

But, the `Uint8ClampedArray` no(1) was different with no(2). Or is it this is an expected behavior? Here is my code :

```
/** first part **/
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data.result;
// wait for image finish load
// then draw image into canvas
img.onload = function () {
    // draw cover image into canvas
    // ctx is just canvas context
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
    // clampedArray is just a normal variable
    clampedArray = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width );
    console.log(clampedArray.data); //<----------------------- (1)
    var base64Image = secret.toDataURL( 'image/jpeg' );
    // sending base64Image to another services
}

/** second part/another page **/
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data.result;
img.onload = function () {
   ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );             
   clampedArray  = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, coverAfter.height,coverAfter.width );
   console.log(clampedArray.data); //<----------------------- (2)
}
```

`data.result` return the same base64, but when i `console.log` for both (1) and (2), i got the different result(`Uint8ClampedArray`)

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, i'll look at it, seems like it the  only way as for now

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the two base64 strings are *not* equal. When you run `secret.toDataURL('image/jpeg')`, you re-encode the original jpeg image, which [(most likely)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841834/is-re-encoding-jpeg-images-an-idempotent-operation) will change the image slightly. Therefore, `base64Image` will not be the same as the original `data.result`.

Comment: Seems like its completely different. Guess need to look at @kaiido 's answer